# ASP.net MVC Bundling not updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-6, bundle

Production system is IIS 6 with wildcard mapping so MVC4 is working.

I am bundling my application's js files. On my local host and test servers I run in debug (no bundle) but on production I build for release to bundle and minify.

I made changes to a .js file, re-built, and re-published (file system publish) and the changes to the .js don't come through via the bundle. However, if I manually copy the unbundled/unminified .js files to the production /Scripts folder it seems to pick them up.

BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/appJs").Include(
"~/Scripts/Time.js",
"~/Scripts/Expense.js"
));
```

.cshtml file

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/appJs")
```

Am I configuring wrongly or is this an issue IIS 6?

Comment: To help identify the problem, can you try doing an iisreset and see if the refreshed bundle works?

Answer (score 0):

It works in IIS 6 for me with the .NET 4.0 aspnet_isapi.dll wildcard mapping. Make sure the verify flag is unchecked when you set that up.

Is this a 64-bit or 32-bit server? I am having a similar issue in Windows Server 2008 64-bit, but do not have access to a 2003 64-bit server to see if fails there as well.